# Compact Support of a function

Tags: measure-theory

The Hat Function :
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{\frac{-1}{1-\mid x^2 \mid}}, & \mid x \mid \lt 1\\
0, & \mid x \mid \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

Prove that $f(x) \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).$

**My approach:**

$$Supp(f(x))= \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f(x) \neq 0\}}$$

As defined above the function,$f(x) \neq 0,$ for $\mid x \mid \lt 1$.That gives $$Supp(f(x))=[-1,1], \text{which is a compact subset of } \mathbb {R} \text{ and so}\\ f \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R}), f \text{ has a compact support}.\\$$
Also, $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable function $\implies f \in  C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).\\$

Is my proof to the question correct or do I need some more steps?

Comment: How do you know $f$ is continuous and that $f^{(k)}$ is well-defined and continuous ?

Comment: An exponential function is continuous everywhere, for the above function, $f$, the only possible discontinuity was at $x=1$, where the function is defined with a zero value. Hence, continuous everywhere.@reuns

Comment: At first $f^{(k)}$ is defined only for $x\ne \pm 1$ how do you know it is well-defined (and continuous) at $x=\pm 1$

Comment: $f(x) = e^{-1/(1-x^2)} = e^{-(1-x^2)^{-1}}=e^{-1-x^2-x^4-x^6- \cdot \cdot \cdot}, \mid x^2 \mid \lt 1.$
Now, $f(x)$ is a product of expotential functions(which are continous and differentiable). Product of continuous and differentiable function is continuous and differentiable respectively. Is that right? @reuns

Comment: No. It is trivial $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $\Bbb{R}-\pm 1$ the problem is to find the behavior at $\pm 1$

Comment: What's wrong with that?- Can I not right it like that?

Comment: Can you prove it for me?

Comment: The problem is to show $f'(1)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} $ is well-defined and similarly for $f^{(k+1)}(1)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^{(k)}(1+h)-f^{(k)}(1)}{h} $

Comment: But how to show that?

Comment: By showing $f'$ is continuous ie. that $\lim_{x \to 1}f'(x)=...$

Comment: I am asking for some $k$-th derivative.

Comment: It works the same way for $f^{(k)}$. So $\lim_{x \to 1}f'(x)=...= ?$